# In SwiftUI, how do I initialize an animated value based on the screen height?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I am new to SwiftUI but a very experienced developer (which may even be a hindrance here). I have a full-screen, highly graphical app/game. One of the requirements is for a specific image to animate by floating up and down. Doing this is easy:

```
@State var y : CGFloat = 400
var rockFloatExtent: CGFloat = 140

var body: some View {
   VStack {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
         Image("Earth1Rocks2")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: self.y)
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 5.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: self.y)
            .onAppear {
               self.y = geometry.size.height * percentRockStartHeight + rockFloatExtent
            }
      }
      ...
```

The problem is the the initial value is going to depend on the state of the game. Sometimes, the y value may be 25% of the screen height (again, full-screen app) and other times it may start at 50% of screen height. At least in the emulator UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height seems to be simply wrong with respect to the device height - it doesn't agree with the GeometryReader at all. I would love an easy way to init the value OR some trick with the animation to make this work.

I have tried doing an .onAppear with an initial value and, after a very brief pause, a second value. But the animation just ignores the first value or varies between all three. I have tried initializing the position using GeometryReader but then the element's y value isn't tied to self.y and the animation breaks. I don't know how to reference (and animate) the *actual* position of the element either without a state variable as an intermediary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler - just switch frame alignment and everything else will be done by SwiftUI:

```
@State private var isAnimating = false  // << state !!

var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "globe")       // << just for demo
        .resizable().scaledToFit()
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: isAnimating ? .top : .bottom)   // << switch !!
        .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 5.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: isAnimating)
        .onAppear {
            isAnimating = true   // << activate !!
        }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Comment: As I noted in the question, getting the basic animation to work isn't a problem. I recognize this as an answer from one of the animation tutorials I've already visited. My problem involves finding a way to start the animation at a location that will change from load to load.

Comment: Suddenly meet this again... Do you mean that you need to start animation somewhere inside the range and then bounce between edges of this range? Like start at 0.75 (of height) then animate to 1 (linearly?) then back to 0 and again to 1 and so forth?

Comment: More like start at 0.5, rise to 0.75, then fall to 0.5, rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

So as you have a game the phone is potentially landscape mode. If so UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height will give you the height of the phone and not the height of the screen, but the width of the screen. UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height does not react on device rotation. It stays the same.
Maybe that the issue you're facing.
Hope that helps.

The solution of @Asperi looks good to me.

Comment: Actually, in a bit of an exception, this one is in landscape. But thanks for the note on how width/height works under rotation.